# Using specific Android version by default for rendering layout files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Whenever I open any XML file than default Android version is **N** an Exception occur while rendering as shown in the figure

[image]

then when I change my Android version to **22** that Exception disappear as shown in figure

[image]

so I want to make default Android version to be used **22** when rendering layout , I mean whenever I open any android XML file it must use **22** for rendering layout by default .
how I can do this ?

> I don't want to uninstall **N**

Comment: You could uninstall N from the SDK Manager if you aren't using it.

Comment: @cricket_007 i don't want to uninstall N :(

Comment: Then don't compile the app with the N SDK?

Comment: please check @AndroidMechanic answer and my comment on that

Comment: Your compileSdk should be 22, and not `'android-N'` or `'23'`

Answer (score 1):

Change the `compileSdkVersion` in your app's `build.gradle` to 22.
The API level you specify there is the one that is used to render your layouts.

Note: You will also need to downgrade the `buildToolsVersion` and the android `support and design librarie`s. when you downgrade `compileSdkVersion`.

Comment: i have Android 6.0 (API 23 ) and Android N(API 23 , N preview) , how both of them have same API 23 ? problem can be resolved if i can use Android 6.0(API 23)?

Comment: thats not possible per my knowledge. What happens if you save the layout file after changing the api level to 22. When you open again does it stay at 22? if that happens you will have to take that one time effort of switching and saving the layout's api level for correct rendering. Otherwise i doubt if there is a global setting you could toggle to achieve what you want.

Comment: i tried to change to 22 and i am getting lots of error as you specified in your answer ..

Comment: did you also change the build tools version and the support library versions?

Comment: i will after trying @Abakasha Panda solution :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]The best solution is to "install jdk 1.8" because android N uses jdk 1.8 to render layout ,After installing jdk 1.8 ,set the jdk location in the Project Structure(you can find project structure in >File -> Project Structure  OR File-> Other Settings ->Default Project Structure  OR Right click on Project -> Open Module Settings ->click on SDK Location at top left corner). After that you don't have to change to sdk 22 to render . I had the same problem it got solved now with above approach .[Check the docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#java8)

Comment: this seems to be a possible solution , let me try :)

Comment: interesting ... did you figure out how that made things work?

Comment: you can go through the link    https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#java8

Comment: Sadly this did not worked for me as well ,i already had `jdk1.8.0_31` even than i updated jdk to `jdk1.8.0_91` , still no luck :( i tried whatever i can with JDK .

Comment: @ManishMenaria did you changed the JDK Location in Project Structure ?

Comment: then may be you can try restarting Android studio

Comment: i tried restarting android studio as well as Laptop :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114321/discussion-between-abakasha-panda-and-manishmenaria).